# How can one completely turn off the incoming audio of a call when using Telegram on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I use Telegram on an iPhone 12 mini with iOS 15. When I am on a call in Telegram, how can I completely turn off the incoming audio of a call when using Telegram on iPhone?

When I use the regular volume buttons on the left side of the iPhone, I cannot completely turn off the incoming audio. It only allows me to reduce the incoming audio but not completely silence the incoming audio:

[image]